# Install SSL Certificate on NGINX / Ubuntu 16.04 x64 (Digital Ocean)

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, nginx, https

I have been trying to install the SSL certificate on my droplet on Digital Ocean. This droplet is running NGINX / Ubuntu 16.04 x64.

I don't have any cPanel just a terminal with SSH connection.

I have also talked to the Digital Ocean's support guy and he shared 2 tutorials with me which I have tried. But following those tutorials end up breaking my site.

**[Tutorial 1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-commercial-certificate-authority#install-certificate-on-web-server)**

**[Tutorial 2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-for-ubuntu-14-04#step-two-%E2%80%94-configure-nginx-to-use-ssl)**

I have edit the **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf** and added the server block like this in `http` block:

```
server {
         listen 443 ssl;
         server_name www.example.com;
         ssl_certificate /home/user/example/www.example.com.crt;
         ssl_certificate_key /home/user/example/www.example.com.key;
}
```

What I'm doing wrong and what is the right way?

I'm confused which file to edit.

I have:

1) /etc/ngix/ngix.conf

2) /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

3) /etc/nginx/sites-available/defaultu

4) /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com

5) /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com

Please I need help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More info is needed as to where you are at. Have you got the certificates onto the droplet yet? If not and you are using a Windows machine to connect via SSH to the droplet, then I would recommend downloading WinSCP as you can use that to transfer the certificates. If you let me know how far you are, I can walk you through the process. Also, you have no listen directives in your server blocks such as:

```
listen 443 ssl;
ssl_certificate /path to .crt or .pem file;
ssl_certificate_key /path to .key file;
```

Comment: Well I'm on mac and have put the SSL certificate and key on the droplet via SSH already. @Sean_space it would be awesome if you walk me through the process :)

Comment: Omer, I have updated my answer above with what you need to include into your second server block. Please let me know when you have add this and then restarted nginx ( sudo service nginx restart ). If you have any errors, please list them. It would be good to continually update your question with any progress you make.

Comment: @Omer Can you also add the following file above: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Comment: If I add the above server block in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf ... and try to restart the service ... this message shows `Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.` .... I added this block at the very bottom of the file

Comment: my .crt and .key file names are different then my domain. Does it affect?

Comment: @Omer when you get the error, if you type in journalctl -xe and copy the logs, that should tell us what is going on.

Comment: @Omer I suggest not putting this in the nginx.conf file, I would put it in the config file that is either located in "/etc/nginx/conf.d" or "/etc/nginx/sites-available" depending on how you have set this up. Remove the server block from your nginx.conf file, and add it to one of the other locations (whichever exists).

Comment: I have updated my questions for the configuration files I have. ... and there is no configuration file in `conf.d `.. Its empty

Comment: Ok I have figured it out... and its working now but I'm seeing default server page when I try to access the site though https ... It seems like I have to define a path as well to the site?

Comment: This answer helped me a lot but I initially needed to enable the SSL in firewall through this command on my server `sudo ufw allow https` and then I added the above snippet in the same server block that was already there.

Comment: Now i cannot access my site through simple http ... How can I fix that my site can be accessed through both protocols?

Comment: you add in a server block for port 80 such as:
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
       server_name name_of_your_website;
    # Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS with a 301 Moved #Permanently response.
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}